# is it possible to reverse the order of onclick events?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to "reverse" the order of the events?
For example, I have this:

```
<a href=# onclick="alert(0);alert(1)">bla</a>
```

Now i want that the event alert(1) will come first, and alert(0) will come later.

Is it possible?

Something like:

```
<a href=# onclick="alert(0);alert(1);ChangeOrder()">bla</a>
```

Comment: Can you use a function ? like `onclick="return functionAlert()"` ?

Comment: You can use recursion here...

Comment: I'm dealing with XSS, so I have no room for building a new function and stuff like that. The link looks like this: onclick="return somefunction ('user',''test');alert(`0`)" (the alert(0) is my injection, and it works but the event "somefunction ..." occourd first and i want to change the order  or  in some way - cancel the somefunction)

Answer (score 1):

A question: what you want really to do ))
but i find it nice task to resolve! as an exercise

and my one of solutions:

```
 <a href=# onclick="alert(0);alert(1);ChangeOrder(this)">bla</a>
 <script>
  function ChangeOrder(that){
    var entire = that.onclick.toString(); 
    var fn_body = entire.substring(entire.indexOf("{") + 1, entire.lastIndexOf("}"));

    var fn_body_parts = fn_body.split(";");
    var new_fn_order  = fn_body_parts[1]+";"+fn_body_parts[0]+";"+fn_body_parts[2];

    that.setAttribute("onclick", new_fn_order);
    console.log(that.onclick);
    console.log(new_fn_order);

  }
</script>
```

working code is here http://plnkr.co/edit/CxDxksea0I3x7Umsyt1B